# Can I change the autonaming of controls when pasting duplicate IDs in Visual Studio 2010 or higher

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

When I copy and paste a control several times, with an ID entered it will prevent duplicate IDs thusly:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExample" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"/>
```

and so on

We tend to use the naming txtDescription. txt for the control, then a meaningful part to the name.

Is there any way to make the templating give those controls names like "txt1","txt1" and so on and so fourth for all other controls.

Comment: Do you use both C# and VB.NET, or only one of the two?

Comment: We use both, but if there were no vb equivalent, that would be fine. I assume the answer might be T4, but I can't find the correct words to research this scenario.

Comment: How hard is it to replace (Ctrl-H) all the `TextBox` occurrences with `txtExample` after you insert the lines?

Comment: I would have to replace id="TextBox with id="txt, to avoid mucking up all the other occurrences. But I still want to know if there is an answer, I could potentially set all common defaults, or data-tags and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Tools> Options> HTML> Miscellaneous and unchecking the 'Auto ID elements on paste in Source view' box?  Does that accomplish what you're wanting?
Short of that, I'll typically make one line

```
<asp:TextBox id="txt" runat="server" />
```

and copy this.  Then change the 'txt' to 'txtDescr'.  So when I paste the next line, there isn't a duplicate ID.

Comment: It doesn't answer this question, but it is helpful - I will give it a spin and see how it works for me, in lieu of actually being able to cotrol that behaviour. Thanks!